# R - replace part of a string using wildcards

Tags: regex, r

I just started using R again, and I was wondering is there a way to replace part of a string using wildcards.

For example:

say I have

```
S1 <- "aaaaaaaaa[aaaaa]aaaa[bbbbbbb]aaaa"
```

and I want to replace everything within square brackets with 'x', such that the new string is

```
"aaaaaaaaa[x]aaaa[x]aaaa"
```

Is this possible to do in R?

Please note what is in the square bracket can be of variable length.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple regex would be like

```
\\[.+?\\]
```

**Example** http://regex101.com/r/xE1rL1/1

**Example Usage**

```
s1 <- 'aaaaaaaaa[aaaaa]aaaa[bbbbbbb]aaaa'
gsub("\\[.+?\\]", "[x]", s1)
## [1] "aaaaaaaaa[x]aaaa[x]aaaa"
```

**Regular expression**

- `\\[` matches opening `[`
- `.+?` non greedy matching of anything
- `\\]` matches closing `]`

**EDIT**

For safety, if nothing is present in the the `[]`, then the regex can be slightly modified as

```
s1 <- 'aaaaaaaaa[]aaaa[bbbbbbb]aaaa'
gsub("\\[.*?\\]", "[x]", s1)
##[1] "aaaaaaaaa[x]aaaa[x]aaaa"
```

Comment: (+1) that's a nice one

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for the edit. Will add some more details to the answer

Comment: what if there is nothing in between the brackets ? like "aaa[]aaa[bbb]" ? maybe you could replace `+` by `*` ?

Comment: @CathG Valid concern !! I have edited my answer to take care of that. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: @nu11p01n73R you're welcome, that was the answer I wanted to post (with `*`) but you were faster. Now, I can upvote ;-)

Comment: Guys just want to say thanks, I was pulling my hair out (what hair I have), to resolve this.

Answer (score 5):

Could also try `qdapRegex` package which has a special method for such problems: `rm_square`

```
library(qdapRegex)
S1 <- "aaaaaaaaa[aaaaa]aaaa[bbbbbbb]aaaa" 
rm_square(S1, replacement = "[x]")
## [1] "aaaaaaaaa[x]aaaa[x]aaaa"
```

Will work the same for empty brackets

```
S1 <- "aaaaaaaaa[]aaaa[bbbbbbb]aaaa" 
rm_square(S1, replacement = "[x]")
## [1] "aaaaaaaaa[x]aaaa[x]aaaa"
```

Comment: Thanks, for this. Another library to add. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use positive lookahead and lookbehind assertions like below.

```
"(?<=\\[)[^\\[\\]]*(?=\\])"
```

Then replace the matched characters with `x`

```
> S1<-'aaaaaaaaa[aaaaa]aaaa[bbbbbbb]aaaa'
> gsub("(?<=\\[)[^\\[\\]]*(?=\\])", "x", S1, perl=TRUE)
[1] "aaaaaaaaa[x]aaaa[x]aaaa"
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\\[)` Positive lookbehind asserts that the string you want to match must be preceded by `[` symbol.
- `[^\\[\\]]*` Matches any character but not of `[` or `]` zero or more times.
- `(?=\\])` Positive lookahead asserts that the match must be followed by `]` symbol.

Comment: lookarounds isn't an overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

```
\\[[^\\]]+
```

You can simply do this without lookaheads or soemthing.Rpelace by `[x`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/13

Comment: Won't work for `aaaaaaaaa[]aaaa[bbbbbbb]aaaa` though. Either way, you can wrap your answer into something like `gsub("\\[[^\\]]+", "[x", s1, perl = TRUE)`